# How to Add Calendar Events to Google Calendar from Flask App without oauth?

Tags: python, flask, google-calendar-api

In my current Flask app, I have a User column in my flask-sql-alchemy database. I handle the creation of the user and login (NOT handled with google login). In the functionality of the flask webapp, calendar events for the future are created from a form. How would I add these events to the user's google calendar without having their oauth information? Without having the users google information, would the following code I found on Google Calendar API website work? Or would this only add to the calendar of account from which the calendar api is initialized.

insert.py

```py
event = {
  'summary': 'Google I/O 2015',
  'location': '800 Howard St., San Francisco, CA 94103',
  'description': 'A chance to hear more about Google\'s developer products.',
  'start': {
    'dateTime': '2015-05-28T09:00:00-07:00',
    'timeZone': 'America/Los_Angeles',
  },
  'end': {
    'dateTime': '2015-05-28T17:00:00-07:00',
    'timeZone': 'America/Los_Angeles',
  },
  'recurrence': [
    'RRULE:FREQ=DAILY;COUNT=2'
  ],
  'attendees': [
    {'email': user.email}
  ],
  'reminders': {
    'useDefault': False,
    'overrides': [
      {'method': 'email', 'minutes': 24 * 60},
      {'method': 'popup', 'minutes': 10},
    ],
  },
}

event = service.events().insert(calendarId='primary', body=event).execute()
print 'Event created: %s' % (event.get('htmlLink'))
```

Functionality this is what I want:

```py
@app.route('/account', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
@login_required
def account():
     form = Form()
     if form.validate.on_submit():
          event = {
            'summary': 'Google I/O 2015',
            'location': '800 Howard St., San Francisco, CA 94103',
            'description': 'A chance to hear more about Google\'s developer products.',
            'start': {
              'dateTime': form.datetime_start.data,
              'timeZone': form.timezone.data,
            },
            'end': {
              'dateTime': form.datetime_end.data,
              'timeZone': form.timezone.data,
            },
            'recurrence': [
              'RRULE:FREQ=DAILY;COUNT=2'
            ],
            'attendees': [
              {'email': current_user.email}
            ],
            'reminders': {
              'useDefault': False,
              'overrides': [
                {'method': 'email', 'minutes': 24 * 60},
                {'method': 'popup', 'minutes': 10},
              ],
            },
          }
          event = service.events().insert(calendarId='primary', body=event).execute() # the event is now in the users calendar
```

Comment: What is the barrier to using OAuth?

Comment: @xdhmoore I guess I am kind of confused about OAuth. Does that mean that each individual user has to provide their OAuth token for me to add calendar events to their google calendar?

Comment: Well, there are different auth flows in OAuth, but the way I've used it is providing a link on my website to google where the user can go and give me access, then google returns them to my site along with an access code I can send to google and get back a token that I use when calling the api. Yeah, it's a little confusing.

Comment: Check out the 'Scenarios' section here: https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2#scenarios

Answer (score 0):

### Approach

If you want to create the events on your users' calendars you will have to get their permission one way or another.

1. If they log with their google credentials in your application they can create directly an event in their calendar. But this require the OAuth2 authentication flow.
2. If you have write permission on one of your users calendar, you can move a newly created event on that calendar using only your credentials.

```py
# First retrieve the event from the API.
updated_event = service.events().move(
    calendarId='primary', eventId='eventId',
    destination='destinationCalendarId').execute()
```

You could add the destinationCalendarId field in your form.

### Consideration

Adding your users to an event as attendees will show the event in their calendar having you as an organizer. If this suffice your needs, this is the easiest way since it only requires your credentials.

### Reference:

[Calendar Sharing settings](https://support.google.com/calendar/answer/37082?hl=en)

[Event move](https://developers.google.com/calendar/v3/reference/events/move#request)